# How can I replicate a table from SQL 2000 to SQL 2008?

Tags: sql, triggers, replicate

I have a table on a SQL Server 2000 database, which I want copied verbatim to a 2008 server.

I tried to do it manually with INSERT/UPDATE triggers, but this technique runs in a distributed transaction, which does not work because I apparently have to enable MSDTC and the firewall; I don't want to do any of that.

Are there any other ways to replicate that table (in real-time) to the 2008 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My first question would be do you really need it to be replicated?**

If you want to reference it real-time in Sql 2008, just do a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(SQL.80).aspx) with a [Synonym](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190626.aspx).  This will make the table act like it is part of your schema, with minor limitations.

Comment: I probably misused the word replication.
I want it to be synchronized permanently, real-time at the least.
If not real-time synchronized, bi-hourly copying is fine with me.
I need options to choose from; I'm so lost.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a [scheduled DTS/SSIS package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933541(SQL.80).aspx) to do the work?

Is it copying or replication? Copying implies a one-time action while replication implies an open-ended period of time during which these tables will be synchronized.

Comment: Refer to the comment I added to the other answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Saw the comment: Bi-hourly (or even more frequent) copies could easily be handled with a scheduled DTS package.